# Unloading DLL while it's code is being executed (From a non-owned thread)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

I have a dynamic link library that will hook certain functions in a host process, redirecting them to my the DLL's detour functions. I want to be able to unload this library on a cue that will be given through a call on one of these hooked functions by the host process. Would it be safe to simply unload the DLL while it's code is being executed?

I am aware that `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` (as opposed to `FreeLibrary`) exists for unloading a library from within a owned thread, halting the execution immediately. However, I am not able to terminate the thread on which the DLL's code will be running on at the time of the unloading.

I have thought of a solution in case it isn't safe: To spawn a thread that will properly unhook everything and exit using `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` afterwards, but I'm not sure that is needed or even the best solution if it is.

Comment: "*Would it be safe to simply unload the DLL while it's code is being executed?*" - of course not. "*I have thought of a solution*" - have you [read this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131105-00/?p=2733) yet? Also have a look at [`FreeLibraryWhenCallbackReturns()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-freelibrarywhencallbackreturns)